# Will Deepin Desktop Enviroment require a Graphic Card?

Tags: system-installation

Deepin Desktop Enviroment requires some real hardware to run. My pc is a i3 8Gb, But 0 dedicated graphic. So I want to know will my my pc lags on performance of deepin desktop enviroment?

Will deepin desktop enviroment require a graphic card to run?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Fedora Deepin Desktop Spin on a 8 year old Thinkpad, i5 16GB RAM no dedicated graphic card without problem.

Should work fine for you too.